# Tell the linux kernel to put a file in the disk cache?

Tags: linux, cache, kernel

Is there any command to for a file to be read in and loaded into the linux disk cache? This is on an up-to-date debian system.

I know in the general case, it's better to let the linux kernel figure this out. But I have an edge case. I have a laptop that has an NFS director mounted, and i want to play a long video file, but I don't want to have a network problem interrupt the playnig. I know that (largeish) file will be read in it's entirety later on. I know that nothing else (really) will be running  while playing this video. There is enough free memory to store this file.

(I know I could just copy the file into a new tmpfs filesystem, but I'm curious if there's an even shorter way to do it)

Answer (score 7):

A small program that `mmap()`ed the file with the `MAP_LOCKED` flag set would do the trick.  You'll need to run this program as root, or a user with an `RLIMIT_MEMLOCK` value greater than the size of the file you want to map.

As [SaveTheRbtz](https://serverfault.com/users/6244) has mentioned, [vmtouch](http://hoytech.com/vmtouch/) has this capability built-in.  The manpage suggests that `vmtouch -l /some/file` will do the trick.

Comment: And don't forget to munlock() that file afterwards again! :)

Comment: Not necessary; as per `mlock`(2), "Memory locks are [...] automatically removed (unlocked) [...] when the process terminates.".

Comment: There is a tool for that: http://hoytech.com/vmtouch/

Comment: @SaveTheRbtz: Thanks for that -- I expected someone would have written it already.

Answer (score 5):

If you really control the local environment that strictly, a simple **cat $file >/dev/null** should be sufficient.
It's quite non-deterministic, when cache eviction removes that file - but if you have plenty of RAM and noone consuming it, it should be kept.

If there is a sticky and deterministic way to keep a file in cache - dunno...

Comment: Is that guaranteed to put the file into the cache though?

Comment: Yes, thats the way it works. It's read through the cache.